# try again a request everytime another request fails in nodejs

Tags: node.js, request

I am trying to make a request through a proxy, but there are certain situations where that proxy doesn't work so i have to use another proxy. this is all cool but the thing is the proxy that i am using is generated by a prior request in the same code, so to use another proxy i need to request it again and i don't know how to do this since the second request is inside the first one (because else i can't use the result the first request returned). Here is how my code looks like:

```
function asyncreq(url, proxy) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    request({
      url: url,
      proxy: proxy
    }, function(error, response, body) {
      if (typeof response !== 'undefined') {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          resolve(response);
          return;
        }
        resolve(response)
        return;
      }
      resolve(error)
    });
  });
}

asyncreq("http://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?api=" + myapikey + "&type=http&country=fr&format=txt&https=true&post=true").then(function(result) { //FIRST REQUEST
  if (result.statusCode == 200 && result.body.includes("http://") == false) {
    var proxy = result.body;
    console.log("using proxy: " + proxy)
    asyncreq("https://haapi.ankama.com/json/Ankama/v2/Account/CreateGuest?game=20&lang=fr", "http://" + proxy).then(function(result) { //SECOND REQUEST
      if (JSON.parse(result.body).key == undefined) {
        // DO STUFF IF IT IS A SUCESS (If it matters, here i intend to make a third request)
      } else {
        console.log(JSON.parse(result.body).key) //HERE I MUST JUMP TO FIRST REQUEST AGAIN
      }
    })
  } else {
    console.log("Error: " + result.body)
  }
})
```

I have tried to return a value if it fails and then execute a while loop but it doesn't work because i can't use the returned value outside the function

Comment: `JSON.parse(result.body).key` is the `myapikey` parameter?

Comment: no that's another parameter, when the request fails it submits a json with a key named "key" but it doesn't submit it when it succeeds so i use it to figure out if the request was a success or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this task with tail-recursion technique.

After the second request you need to choose if repeat the first one or continue to the third.
Thanks to the promise chaining, you can attach a promise to the chain and all it's children (`.then`).

This example should works:

```
function asyncreq(url, proxy, validateResponse) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({ url, proxy }, function (error, response, body) {
      if (response && validateResponse(response)) {
        resolve(response)
        return;
      }
      reject(response || error)
    });
  });
}

let sharedProxy;    

function firstRequest(myapikey) {
  const firstCallValidation = (response) => {
    return typeof response !== 'undefined' && result.statusCode == 200 && result.body.includes("http://") == false;
  }

  return asyncreq(`http://pubproxy.com/api/proxy?api=${myapikey}&type=http&country=fr&format=txt&https=true&post=true`, null, firstCallValidation)
    .then(function (result) { //FIRST REQUEST
      var proxy = result.body;
      console.log("using proxy: " + proxy)
      sharedProxy = proxy;
      return secondRequest(proxy)
    })
    .then(function (result) { //SECOND REQUEST
      if (JSON.parse(result.body).key == undefined) {
        // DO STUFF IF IT IS A SUCESS (If it matters, here i intend to make a third request)
        return thirdRequest(sharedProxy);
      }
      //HERE I MUST JUMP TO FIRST REQUEST AGAIN
      const apiKey = JSON.parse(result.body).key
      return firstRequest(apiKey)
    });
}

function secondRequest(proxy) {
  return asyncreq("https://haapi.ankama.com/json/Ankama/v2/Account/CreateGuest?game=20&lang=fr", "http://" + proxy, () => true)
}

function thirdRequest(proxy) {
  return asyncreq("https://ha...." + proxy);
}

// Start!!
firstRequest()
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error: ", err)
  })
```

Comment: So sophisticated, works like a charm. Thank you. But how can I still keep the value of the proxy to use it again on the third request? Excuse my ignorance i am not that smart and I just started learning node.js

Comment: nevermind i found a way, well it's not exactly clean but it will do, i fetched it from the result of the request: http://satanbot.ueuo.com/pics/cmd_2018-12-21_18-35-41.png
if you have a better way please share it :)

Comment: quite simple, i have edit the response. I think that example is usefull to understand the promise chaining because is very important. You can check here also: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Answer (score 0):

Include a `reject` in your promise: `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { reject(error) }` then call `asyncreq` again upon rejection of your Promise.

Comment: thank you, it's the same solution Manuel proposed and it works. :D